# Is it possible to create private property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, private

Is it possible to create private property in Objective-C?
I do know that a kind of private property functionality could be implemented in another way but I'm interested in particular question.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing.  I want to hide all the retain/release code for a particular variable that is contained in a class, but that variable is not meant to be public.

Comment: JFYI, now with iOS SDK 5 ARC you don't need to care about retain and release anymore :)

Comment: That's what I hear, I'm very excited to see.  Sorry, getting off topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can, but the code will looks a little bit strange. And it will only give you some warning if you call, you have to check for the warnings yourself

in your implementation file .m

```
@interface YourObject ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *infoArray;

@end
```

Comment: And even this solution won't create true private property since it will be accessible for external code. Even without a warning if called though setValue:forKey:

Comment: What do you mean by that? if I call like YourObject *obj = //alloc init; then obj.infoArray, it will give me warning. You are doing KVO?

Comment: @vodkhang:  Why do you say the code will look strange?  It looks fairly normal to me.

Comment: @Gobra: -setValue:forKey: will not generate a compile time warning at all for any property private, public or even non existent.

Comment: @JeremyP : I am not so sure if anybody does it or not. The first time I try, it looks strange because like you create a category without any name:)

Comment: @vodkhang: Thanks, that's the point! I've just worked with pseudo private methods and missed the fact that private properties could be declared in the same way as well. Thanks!

Comment: @NR4TR: properties are just a pair of methods.  @vodkhang: Yes, it's a standard thing called a class extension.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html

Comment: @JeremyP: I do know the fact that property is a pair of getter and setter, I've meant just some abstract pseudo private class. Nevertheless thank for the knowledge-refreshing link :)