# private property in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to declare a private property in Objective C? The goal is to benefit from synthesized getters and setters implementing a certain memory management scheme, yet not exposed to public.

An attempt to declare a property within a category leads to an error:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSArray *_someArray;
}

...

@end

@interface MyClass (private)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray   *someArray;

@end

@implementation MyClass (private)

@synthesize someArray = _someArray;
// ^^^ error here: @synthesize not allowed in a category's implementation

@end

@implementation MyClass

...

@end
```

Comment: Why have a private property? When you can just access the `*_someArray` directly inside your instance methods?

Comment: Possible Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665698/is-it-possible-to-create-private-property-in-objective-c

Comment: Private properties are a great place to put things like lazy loading logic for ivars

Comment: @property synthesizes proper accessors, and makes the property conformant to KVC (key-value-coding) and KVO (key-value-observing) protocols, provides better concurrency support, and adds support for many high-level  language features (declaring validation rules, dependency of property on other properties when they change, and much more).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I implement my private properties like this.

MyClass.m

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *someArray;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize someArray;

...
```

That's all you need.

Comment: To expand on this, Objective-C doesn’t really have the concept of private methods. You can call any method you like as long as you know the name. This is what allows you to call private methods in Apple’s classes, even though they don’t exist in the headers.

Comment: "That's all you need." :D 
Never used so much code for just defining a simple property

Comment: These days you don't even need the `@synthesize`.

Comment: I thought you had to declare properties in .h file?

Comment: @cheznead: That's the idea behind declaring the property in the '.m' file vs the '.h' file.

Comment: Make sure to not set a name on your category in the .m file like this `@interface MyClass (DontPutMeHere)`otherwise auto synthesize won't work

Answer (score 12):

**A.** If you want a completely private variable. Don't give it a property.
**B.** If you want a readonly variable that is accessible external from the encapsulation of the class, use a combination of the global variable and the property:

```
//Header    
@interface Class{     
     NSObject *_aProperty     
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSObject *aProperty;

// In the implementation    
@synthesize aProperty = _aProperty; //Naming convention prefix _ supported 2012 by Apple.
```

Using the readonly modifier we can now access the property anywhere externally.

```
Class *c = [[Class alloc]init];    
NSObject *obj = c.aProperty;     //Readonly
```

But internally we cannot set aProperty inside the Class:

```
// In the implementation    
self.aProperty = [[NSObject alloc]init]; //Gives Compiler warning. Cannot write to property because of readonly modifier.

//Solution:
_aProperty = [[NSObject alloc]init]; //Bypass property and access the global variable directly
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends what you mean by "private".

If you just mean "not publicly documented", you can easily enough use a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) in a private header or in the .m file.

If you mean "others are not able to call it at all", you're out of luck. Anyone can call the method if they know its name, even if it is not publicly documented.

Comment: > "Anyone can call the method if they know its name, even if it is not publicly documented."
- Secure computing at its finest :-(

Comment: @BronDavies objective-c uses the "messaging" paradigm where you send messages to an object. The name of the property is just the contents of the message, and the value of the property is just the object's response to the message. If you want security with any messaging system, you need to use encryption. The property name could be derived from a private key perhaps, and maybe it changes every 30 seconds. Security is certainly possible in obj-c if you need that. I can't imagine why you would though... I make my properties private so that I can change them later without breaking external code.

Comment: There is a proper guide on secure application coding in ObjC. ObjC is dynamic in nature and it has nothing to do with security. Approaching ObjC with C++ in mind is not optimal. ObjC security does not imply, and does not stem from limiting, crippling and obfuscating your code. Other ways are used. Separation of concerns, breaking app into several "XPC Services" each with its own and limited capabilities, etc. Property accessor method can authenticate and identify caller and deny access.

Answer (score 6):

As others have indicated, (currently) there is no way to truly declare a private property in Objetive-C.

One of the things you can do to try and "protect" the properties somehow is to have a base class with the property declared as `readonly` and in your subclasses you can redeclare the same property as `readwrite`.

Apple's documentation on redeclared properties can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW19

Comment: I found that the use of {}'s was a bit fiddly and I just wanted to point that out here;

In the .m file I had to declare the "private" property *after* the {} block; (pardon the poor formatting...)
   `@interface MyClass() {
        SKProductsRequest* _request;
        NSMutableArray* _productLocales;
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;
    @end
    
    @implementation MyClass
    @synthesize request = _request;
    ...`