# @interface keyword in the *.m file

Tags: objective-c

I am just want to know if there is any difference between:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property ...
@end
```

in the *.h file and:

```
@interface AppDelegate()
@property ...
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
```

in the *.m file.

When do I need prefer the first version and when it will be better to use second version ?

Comment: Public interface versus private class extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you can put in a .h file you can put in a .m file.  The contents of an imported .h are directly copied into the .m during the early stages of compilation, so there is no syntactic difference based on where a statement is placed.

But you will note that there *is* a difference in syntax between

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
```

and

```
@interface AppDelegate()
```

The second form is an *extension* of the already-described interface, vs being a new (and conflicting) version.  The fact that it is placed in the .m (which is not required -- it could be placed in the .h without raising an error) means that any other module importing the .h will not "see" it, making it "private" (as much as anything in Objective-C is private).

Comment: Why it is impossible to declare '@property' in the '@implementation' section of *.m file to make it private (as I can declare private variable) ? Why do I need use '@interface' section to declare private property ?  Is there any logic in this restriction ?

Comment: @demas -- That's the way the language was speced.  It probably makes sense to the compiler writer from a simplicity standpoint.

Answer (score 4):

### **Public Vs. Private**

Basically, the **.h** file is your *public* header, and your **.m** file is your *implementation* (**private**).

Whatever you put in your `@interface` in your **.m** will be *private* (class extensions and what not), and your `@interface` in your **.h** is *public*.

If I was going to pass stuff to the UIViewController using a segue, or if I needed access to the data in some object I would put my `@properties` in my **.h**. Otherwise I just put everything in the private class extension (**.m**). You could get away with only using your `@properties` in the **.h** file though.

Comment: Why it is impossible to declare '@property' in the '@implementation' section of *.m file to make it private (as I can declare private variable) ?  Why do I need use '@interface' section to declare private property ?

Comment: @demas, usually, such demarkations are used to extract useful info by other tools such as testsuites etc. These rules help them identify where to look inside a class for its properties, nothing else.

Comment: Like what Nirav said your @interface is where you tell what properties the class has. The implementation is where you implement methods not define properties.

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
@interface AppDelegate()
@property ...
@end
```

Creates a private class extension which cannot be seen from outside the class implementation file, making it *private*, as opposed to those in the header file which are *public*.

It's still possible to call the private property from other classes, once you have suppressed the compiler warnings, given the dynamic nature of Objective-C.

It's also useful for declaring *private* methods, which I prefix with `_` to differentiate them from public methods, although there is no requirement to do that.

```
@interface AppDelegate()
- (BOOL)_doCoolThing;
@end
```

You don't even have to declare the private methods, given the compiler will work fine with just the definition, however I always do both declare and define them.

Comment: Why it is impossible to declare '@property' in the '@implementation' section of *.m file to make it private (as I can declare private variable) ?  Why do I need use '@interface' section to declare private property ?

Comment: @demas Because `@property` declarations can only appear in the `@interface` section, not the `@implementation` section, and therefore it's necessary to use a class extension if you wish to add properties to the existing properties.

Comment: "Minor" detail.  The fact that it's in the .m is what makes the class extension "private".  Has nothing to do with the actual byte pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you use the `@interface` in the header file (.h) to declare **public** properties and methods, which are visible to other classes that import this class.

The `@interface` in you implementation file (.m) is used to declare **private** properties and methods, which are only visible within that class, and cannot be used or accessed by other classes in your project.

Comment: Why it is impossible to declare '@property' in the '@implementation' section of *.m file to make it private (as I can declare private variable) ?  Why do I need use '@interface' section to declare private property ?

Comment: I guess it is just the way objective-c was defined. Once I used a private property because I wanted to access its value from another instance of the same class, yet I didn't want that property to be visible to instances of other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between your code is that in first variant you use extensions (all methods inside only for @implementation use below)

in .m file

```
@interface ClassName() {
//methods here
}
@end
@implementation ClassName
//method implementation from ClassName() and from .h file for ClassName
@end
```

and in second it's class implementation - all methods that you declare in .h are like public

More details about extension you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

More about classes - [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1)

Information about properties - [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1)

Comment: Why it is impossible to declare '@property' in the '@implementation' section of *.m file to make it private (as I can declare private variable) ?  Why do I need use '@interface' section to declare private property ?

Comment: in Objective C there is no such things like "private" or "public", all methods that you declare by default are "public", if you want to hide something you can use declaration of your property inside  implementation file (but this property can be used only in this file). More about property - look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643130/private-property-in-objective-c

Comment: @Kirill - Actually, a "private" property/method can be used outside of the .m if the user creates the appropriate dummy declaration.