# Objective-C: How do you denied access to parent properties from subclasses?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have this classes defined, how do I denied access to the `someObject` property in sub-subclasses?

```
@interface ForeignSuperClass
// I can not modify the file
@property (nonatomic) NSObject *someObject;
@end
```

.

```
@interface MySubClass : ForeignSuperClass
// this is good for reuse someObject
// but how can I be denied access to the someObject for SubClasses - MySubClass
@end
```

to those who will inherit my class `MySubClass`, did not have access to property `someObject`

Comment: we are not talking about the KVO

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `@property` declaration in your .m file instead of your .h file.  This will make it not visible in subclasses (assuming you aren't importing your .m file, that is).

It's worth noting this only hides the property.  You can technically still access the methods by using any of the dynamic messaging techniques available in Objective-C and the iOS SDK (`like setValue:forKey:`, etc).

Comment: Maybe this will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643130/private-property-in-objective-c

Comment: sorry but i can not modify ```SuperClass``` file, and yes, I know about KVO, but we are not talking about the KVO

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin If you cannot modify the way that the super class declares the property, then there is no way to hide the visibility of it.

Answer (score 0):

To access, from a subclass, a property defined in a super class, you use the self keyword. As in

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.someObject);
```