# Xcode: declaring private @property it complain (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode11.2.1

I'm trying to declare a private property but I'm getting this error:

`Unexpected '@' in program`

Here is my implementation

```
@implementation MyClassImplementation

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *new;

@end
```

Here is where I get the error `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *new;` any of you knows why I'm getting this error or if there is a work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [private property in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643130/private-property-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

Private properties usually are declared in .m file in class unnamed category and for following Cocoa naming convention shouldn't use `new` keyword:

```c
@interface MyClassImplementation ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;

@end

@implementation MyClassImplementation

....

@end
```

Comment: For the sake of correct terminology, `@interface MyClassImplementation ()` is NOT unnamed/anonymous category, but it's a class extension. See [Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3).

Comment: @zrzka Thanks for your notice but from the doc: "Because no name is given in the parentheses, class extensions are often referred to as anonymous categories." so it can be named this way.